# App suddenly stops receiving location

Tags: android, location

I'm using Google Play Services to get location updates. The app works fine for a few days and then it suddenly stops receiving location updates. Only way to restart the location service updates is by rebooting the phone. How do I solve this?

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;


/**
 * BackgroundLocationService used for tracking user location in the background.
 *
 * @author cblack
 */
public class GoogleLocationService extends Service implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener {

    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    // Flag that indicates if a request is underway.
    private boolean mInProgress;

    private Boolean servicesAvailable = false;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public GoogleLocationService getService() {
            return GoogleLocationService;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInProgress = false;
        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

        servicesAvailable = servicesConnected();

        /*
         * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
         * handle callbacks.
         */
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    }

    private boolean servicesConnected() {

        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        if(!servicesAvailable || mLocationClient.isConnected() || mInProgress)
            return START_STICKY;

        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
        if(!mLocationClient.isConnected() || !mLocationClient.isConnecting() && !mInProgress)
        {
            //appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Started", Constants.LOG_FILE);
            mInProgress = true;
            mLocationClient.connect();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /*
     * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
     * handle callbacks.
     */
    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded()
    {
        if(mLocationClient == null) 
            mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    }

    // Define the callback method that receives location updates
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Report to the UI that the location was updated
        /*
        String msg = Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Log.v("debug location xxx", msg);
        // Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        appendLog(getTime() + " " + msg, Constants.LOCATION_FILE);
        */
        String msg = Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("com.idm.LocationUpdate");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("lat", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("lng",  Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        // Turn off the request flag
        mInProgress = false;
        if(servicesAvailable && mLocationClient != null) {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            // Destroy the current location client
            mLocationClient = null;
        }
        // Display the connection status
        // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Stopped", Constants.LOG_FILE);
        super.onDestroy();  
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        // Request location updates using static settings
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        //appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Connected", Constants.LOG_FILE);

    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Turn off the request flag
        mInProgress = false;
        // Destroy the current location client
        mLocationClient = null;
        // Display the connection status
        // Toast.makeText(this, DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //appendLog(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + ": Disconnected", Constants.LOG_FILE);
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        mInProgress = false;

        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {

        // If no resolution is available, display an error dialog
        } else {

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case, I'd stop receiving location updates if the airplane mode in the device is switched on and then back off again. Is this the case for you as well?

Comment: Nope. Mine stops even with airplane mode switched off.